# border layout breaks window

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to put some label/fields in a dialog/window. See below

[image]

I would like to ***stretch*** the field part to maximum, and I would like to ***shrink*** the label to the allowed minimum.

I thought border layout would be the best in that situation :

```
   {
        xtype: 'panel',
        //flex: 1,
        margin: '3',
        border: true,
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'label',
                region: 'west',
                text: 'label'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                region: 'center'
            }
        ]
    }
```

However when I do that, the field disappears and even more strangely, the dialog moves to the (0,0) position in the frame. Ie. the dialog moves to the top left corner :

[image]

Am I not understanding something here? The dialog also uses a border layout. Ie the buttons are in a south panel. Is it maybe not allowable to use a border inside a border for a dialog? Is this an extjs bug?

Is there some other way to achieve what I want to do? I understand you can use **fieldLabel** on a textfield. But I wanted to have two seperate components so I could have more control.

Comment: A border layout?! Use a hbox layout.

Comment: what if i want 100% stretch for the component on the right?

Comment: ok figured out , use flex:1 on the component that is to be streched